# Does kalki avatar happen once in kalpa?

Tags: avatars, bhagavata-purana, kali-yuga, kalki, kalki-purana

Kalki is prophesied as the 10th avatar of lord vishnu.
Lord krishna comes once in a kalpa  and lord ramchandra as well. What about lord kalki ? Can you confirm whether lord krishna and ram also come once in a kalpa ?

Comment: Avatar Kalki only comes once in this Kalpa.